# Need AMD motherboard with AM3 socket that can handle more than 75 watt TDP

Tags: motherboard

I have an AMD Phenom II x6 1055t CPU (AM3 socket), and DDR3 RAM. My motherboard can only support CPUs up to 75 watt TDP, and my CPU is 150W.

Please recommend me a motherboard that:

- Supports a 150W TDP CPU
- Uses an AM3 socket
- Has DDR3 RAM slots
- Costs around $100

Comment: AFAIK, there are no AM3 CPUs with a TDP of 150w. Which CPU do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://www.amazon.com/M5A99FX-PRO-R2-0-990FX-Motherboard/dp/B008B6ONXK/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1498491905&sr=8-4&keywords=asus+am3+motherboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008B6ONXK)

This should work fine. Personally I splurged a bit and got one of these: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008YDJHWM/ref=od_aui_detailpages01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008YDJHWM)

It's a pretty fantastic board, and they've come out with revision 3 since then which has M.2 SSD compatibility. I mean how much you spend depends on your upgrade schedule and whether or not you want to jump to ryzen later on, if you wanted to do that I wouldn't spend a ton on this board as your CPU is getting on in years (I rocked a Phenom II 965 BE until last year, loved that little guy). Both of these boards support my current FX-8350; this is relevant because your CPU's TDP is 125W according to the spec sheet on AMD's website, as opposed to 150W like you stated in your post. The FX-8350 also has a TDP of 125W, so both of these boards should support your CPU.

Careful on your RAM by the way. Whatever board you buy, you need to grab a .pdf of their mobo manual and make sure that your current RAM kit is listed in there for compatibility. Not every RAM kit is manufacturer-tested, so unless you want to end up buying new RAM and waiting another two weeks for shipping after a frustrating Saturday afternoon of troubleshooting, check the literature and save yourself the hassle. Best place to start looking is just to look up your old motherboard, and find the slightly updated version of it.